# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, addeventlistener

I have inputted this code into jfiddle and also into this post and it works perfectly, very simple, on click the picture will change. However, when put into visual studio code (VSC), I get this code error from the console and the picture will not change on click:

"script.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at script.js:5"

I think this could be a problem with an extension I need for VSC? A linking issue?

Here is my code:

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main")
const bill = document.getElementById("bill")
const nick = document.getElementById("nick")

main.addEventListener("click", () => {
bill.classList.toggle("hide")
nick.classList.toggle("hide")
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
nav {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
  
</nav>

<header>
  <h1>Screen Legends</h1>
  <p>A website dedicated to the legends of the silver screen</p>
</header>

<main id="main">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="bill murray" id="bill">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="nick cage" class="hide"id="nick">
</main>
</html>
```

Thank you,

Jack

Comment: Keep `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`  tag end of the body tag`</body>`.

Comment: Use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event. i.e. `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed. Now you can bind event ');
});`

Comment: You are trying to fetch main element in header before it was rendered in body... Ether move  script it to end of the document or wait the document to be loaded with EventListener ... Or put it in function and call function after doc has loaded... And btw your HTML is WRONG: you have empty body tag...

Comment: IkiK, thank you. Adding the script tag of the end of the html has worked. The empty body was there as I was moving the script tag between the body and header tags to see if that changed anything and forgot to remove. Thank you again. This is my first post and what service, amazing response time by 3 people.